# How to use <IF> comparison in $http.post {} section

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to use IF statement in $http.post {} section.

I have written the code as below:

[controller.js]

```
$http.post("../crud/projects_update.php",{
    step_number : $scope.step_number,
    //step_one start
    if(step_number == 1){ // This is where I get an error.
        project_id : $scope.project_data.project_id,    
        project_title : $scope.project_data.project_title
    }
})
.then(function(response){
    // do something here
});
```

However, I get an error on (step_number == 1) part with red underline on '==' part.

I thought it would be working in a simple IF statement form.

Perhaps, I am not using the IF statement in correct comparison syntax..
I have no idea why it is giving me a red line on the '=='.

Does anyone know what could possibly wrong? Please advise me how to fix this error.

Thank you so much in advance!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that the second parameter for the `$http.post` function is an object, and you can't use `if` statements when you are creating an object literal.

That's not an AngularJS thing - it's flat out invalid JavaScript.

---

There are many possible ways you could do what you're trying to do.

One possible solution is:

```
$http.post("../crud/projects_update.php",{
    step_number : $scope.step_number,
    project_id : $scope.step_number === 1 ? $scope.project_data.project_id : undefined,    
    project_title : $scope.step_number === 1 ? $scope.project_data.project_title : undefined
})
```

Comment: I upvoted as you beat me to the punch :)

However, although `undefined` is valid JavaScript, it's not valid JSON. Maybe substitute `undefined` with `null`? (At very least)

Comment: While I understand your point, the object isn't a JSON object nor is it valid JSON (the properties would need to be surrounded by `"` for example)

Comment: @LuisEstevez when run through JSON.stringify() which will be done internally an undefined property is removed which basically does what OP is attempting to do ... try `console.log(JSON.stringify({foo:1,bar:undefined}))// '{"foo":1}'`

Comment: Thank you all for the answers! I have another question though. Why do you have to put undefined at the end?

Comment: Moreover, it says,I get "step_number is not defined" yet that was working before commencing this kind of way you told me. Is there something I might have left out?

Comment: @JamesD wrt your second comment, I have updated the answer.

Comment: @JamesD. wrt your first comment, the ternary operator requires 3 arguments - the condition (before the `?`), an expression to run if the condition is true (before the `:`) and an expression to run if the condition is false (after the `:`). See the mdn documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind and swift answer! I really hope this helps the others as well! :)